# How to display rating bar stars in two lines?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have rating bar widget in my layout and set custom style in layout.
I want to set more that 10 stars in my rating bar, i want to display rating bar stars in two line, as in single line it cut off.

Here is my layout.

```
  <RatingBar
        style="@style/starRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="10"
        android:stepSize="1" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe have two Rating Bars of 5 stars second one below the first one ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to linebreak a single RatingBar, so here is what I suggest:

Make TWO RatingBars and set their OnRatingBarChangeListeners to interact with one another.

I wrote up a quick example to show you exactly what I mean:

### activity_my.xml

This would be your layout file. I used the default name when creating a new project in AS.
Use RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/bar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="10"
    android:stepSize="1" />
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/bar2"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="4"
    android:stepSize="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### MyActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RatingBar;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private RatingBar ratingBar1;
    private RatingBar ratingBar2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        setOnChangeListeners();


    }

    public void setOnChangeListeners(){

        ratingBar1 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.bar1);
        ratingBar2 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.bar2);

        ratingBar1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                ratingBar2.setRating(0);
                ratingBar1.setRating(v);
            }
        });

        ratingBar2.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                ratingBar1.setRating(10);
                ratingBar2.setRating(v);
            }
        });

    }



}
```

As you can see: we use a helper function: `setOnChangeListeners()` to initialize `ratingBar1` and `ratingBar2`. After that we set `onRatingChanged` for both bars. For the first line bar made of 10 stars, we make sure `ratingBar2` is set to 0. For the second bar, if it is changed, `ratingBar1` must be set to 10 so it will be full.

Try it out! Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Rating bar can't break in two line so add rating bar layout dynamically

```
int noOfStarts = 8;
    int noOfRatingLine = (noOfStarts/5)+1;

    LinearLayout[] linear = new LinearLayout[noOfRatingLine];
    RatingBar[] ratingBarNames = new RatingBar[noOfRatingLine];

    for(int i =0;i<noOfRatingLine;i++)
    {
        linear[i] = (LinearLayout)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.app_ratingbar, null);
        ratingBarNames[i] = (RatingBar)linear[i].findViewById(R.id.rating);

        if(noOfStarts<5){
            ratingBarNames[i].setNumStars(noOfStarts);
        }
        else{
            ratingBarNames[i].setNumStars(5);
        }
        ratingBarNames[i].setStepSize(1);
        noOfStarts = noOfStarts-5;

        ratingbarLayout.addView(linear[i]);
    }
```

XML layout app_ratingbar.xml for inflate

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RatingBar>
```